# style elements when page loads in ionic 2

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I am trying to style my images according to some conditions and trying to show them when the page opens/loads.

```
design_on_const(){
    var cover1 = document.getElementById("cover1");
    var cover2 = document.getElementById("cover2");
    var cover3 = document.getElementById("cover3");
    var cover4 = document.getElementById("cover4");
    var cover5 = document.getElementById("cover5");
    cover3.style['visibility']="hidden";
    cover4.style['visibility']="hidden";
    cover5.style['visibility']="hidden";
    if (localStorage.getItem('gardirop_model') == 'surgulu' && localStorage.getItem('gardirop_size') == '132') {
        this.cover_1_prop.top = "0px";
        this.cover_1_prop.left = "14%";
           this.cover_1_prop.maxHeight = "98%"; 

  this.cover_2_prop.style['top'] = "0px";
  this.cover_2_prop.style['left'] = "51%";
  this.cover_2_prop.style['maxHeight'] = "98%";
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('gardirop_model') == 'surgulu' && localStorage.getItem('gardirop_size') == '220') {
        cover1.style['top'] = "0px";
        cover1.style['left'] = "10%";
        cover1.style['maxHeight'] = "97%";

        cover2.style['left'] = "52%";
        cover2.style['maxHeight'] = "91%";
        cover2.style['top'] = "6px";
    }
    if (localStorage.getItem('gardirop_model') == 'menteseli' && localStorage.getItem('gardirop_size') == '132') {
        cover1.style['top'] = "-1%";
        cover1.style['left'] = "13%";
        cover1.style['maxHeight'] = "100%";

        cover2.style['top'] = "-1%";
        cover2.style['left'] = "50%";
        cover2.style['maxHeight'] = "100%";
    }
    //menteseli 220cm
    if (localStorage.getItem('gardirop_model') == 'menteseli' && localStorage.getItem('gardirop_size') == '220') {

        cover1.style['top'] = "0px";
        cover1.style['left'] = "8%";
        cover1.style['width'] = "20%";
        cover1.style['maxHeight'] = "98%";

        cover2.style['top'] = "-1%";
        cover2.style['left'] = "24%";
        cover2.style['maxHeight'] = "99%";
        cover2.style['width'] = "20%";

        cover3.style['visibility'] = "visible";
        cover4.style['visibility'] = "visible";
        cover5.style['visibility'] = "visible";
    }
    console.log("done!");
}
```

This is my function which sets values to elements and I have called this function like `this.design_on_const();` in constructor, ionViewDidLoad, ngOnInit, ionViewDidEnter and the other lifecycle events. It does work, writes "done" to console, but, my styles are not shown. 
Local storage values had been set in previous pages, so, according to these values I have to show my images in this page when page loads. But, images doesn't seem as I wanted. They are just shown randomly placed on the page like they are taking default values. How can I style them in best way or where should I call my function in?

These are my images in html:

```
<ion-col width-25>
    <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
        <img class="gardirop" src="{{gardirop}}" style="width: 90%;" />

        <img id="cover1" class="cover_1" src="{{gardirop_cover_1}}" />
        <img id="cover2" class="cover_2" src="{{gardirop_cover_2}}" />

        <img id="cover3" class="cover_3" src="{{gardirop_cover_3}}" />
        <img id="cover4" class="cover_4" src="{{gardirop_cover_4}}" />
        <img id="cover5" class="cover_5" src="{{gardirop_cover_5}}" />
    </div>
</ion-col>
```

And my .scss file:

```
.gardirop {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;

}
.cover_1 {
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
}
.cover_2 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
.cover_3 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top:-4px;
    left:41%;
    max-height: 99%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
.cover_4 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top:6px;
    left:60%;
    max-height: 90%;
    display: inline-block;

}
.cover_5 {
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
    top:7px;
    left:74%;
    max-height: 89%;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16%;
}
```

Edit:variables definitions

```
        export class KararPage {
    //here
    cover_1_prop:any={};
    cover_2_prop:any={};
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
        this.design_on_const();
    } 
    design_on_const(){
      ...............}
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing elements with `document.getElementById` and changing the DOM directly does not work with Angular 2/Ionic 2 as you intend.
For your case I think [ngStyle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgStyle-directive.html) would work easily.
Create objects containing your style properties:

```
    cover_1_prop:any={};//class variable

 //in your function
this.cover_1_prop.visibility='hidden';
        if (localStorage.getItem('gardirop_model') == 'surgulu' && localStorage.getItem('gardirop_size') == '132') {
        this.cover_1_prop.top = "0px";
        this.cover_1_prop.left = "14%";
        this.cover_1_prop.maxHeight = "98%";
        }
```

In the html,

```
<img id="cover1" class="cover_1" [ngStyle]="cover_1_prop" src="{{gardirop_cover_1}}" />
```

If you want to set css class or update it from component you can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html).

[**Sample Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/b0cM4h9l8WeRiTcOL1Wh?p=preview)

Comment: thank you so much for your reply. If i dont use "document.getElementById", how can i define "cover_1_prop" because writing just "this.cover_1_prop.top = "0px";" gaved me an error. And I have to say something if i write this function in a button click event it works and changes all the style but i dont want this way, not clicking something, just want changing on load, as i said. i think smt crushes my orders in function, what do you think? @suraj

Comment: what error did you get? you can set it in a lifecycle hook and angular will detect

Comment: A syntask error, property cover_1_prop does not exist on type 'pagename'  @suraj i add "[ngStyle]="cover_1_prop" in element in html and saved. angular cant detect i think

Comment: did you declare as class variable?

Comment: Ok, i declared it. Now the error is "Runtime Error
Error in ./Adim4 class Adim4 - caused by: Cannot set property 'top' of undefined" @suraj

Comment: sry.. initialize it in the beginning.. my bad

Comment: no problem, i have tried both, like "var cover_1_prop;" in function or "cover_1_prop:any;" in the beginning, same error @suraj

Comment: cover_1_prop:any={}; //set empty object.. it needs initialization

Comment: I have done just you said but the same error, what can i try next? @suraj

Comment: Sorry can i ask, did you notice that i said it works in my way when i try in a button click event with accessing elements with document.getElementById... @suraj

Comment: yes.. if you are setting an object how is it showing undefined? can you add the code to the question?

Comment: Check the plunkr

Comment: it is okay but this one does not meet my need. @suraj

Comment: I have imported these,  import { Alert} from 'ionic-angular/index';

import {Modal} from "ionic-angular/index";
import {ViewController} from "ionic-angular/index"; and then it works now thank you so much @suraj